# Timber Pagination: page.php / not showing up

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, twig, timber

In the Timber for Wordpress DOCs ([link](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/pagination/)) they say

> This will only work in a php file with an active query (like
>   **archive.php** or **home.php**) (...)

By my understanding, what I have done, is an active query (?).
I need the pagination on one of my page.php sites however.

I can not get the pagination to display.

*page.php*

```
$context['blogposts'] = new Timber\PostQuery(array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'posts_per_page'=> 2,
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'order'         => 'DESC',
    'paged'         => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
));
```

*page.twig*

```
<div id="blogposts-container">
    {% for post in blogposts %}
      {% include ['tease-'~post.post_type~'.twig', 'tease.twig'] %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>

  {% include 'partial/pagination.twig' with { pagination: blogposts.pagination({show_all: false, mid_size: 3, end_size: 2}) } %}
```

This pretty much exact logic works for the index + article pages (yes I tested it).
How can I get it to work for a page/custom page?

Dumping **blogposts.pagination** gives me the *correct* list of items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out i should have shown the **pagination.twig** too.
In my case I had to:

```
{% set posts = blogposts %}
```

for this partial to work.
Due to the partial using posts as the base object for displaying content.